# Rate of decay of the tail of Dirichlet series for Euler's totient function

Tags: nt.number-theory

I am interested in the rate of decay of the sum

$$\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac{\phi(n)}{n^{s}}$$
where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function and $s>2$ (in which case the sum converges trivially).
Of course there's the trivial bound $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac{\phi(n)}{n^{s}}\leq\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{s-1}}\leq C(s)\frac{1}{N^{s-2}}$.
I'm wondering if it's possible to do any better.

Comment: You can use the lower bound $\phi(n) \geq C \frac{n}{\log \log n}$ to get the other direction. Here you can take $C \approx e^{-\gamma}$ for large $n$. So in particular, you cannot get any better power saving.

Comment: Some improvement in the constant can be had by looking at n a multiple of small primes.  Big primes don't help.  Gerhard "Not Seeing Any Power Saving" Paseman, 2018.04.17.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible to do any better. We have

$$\sum_{X\leq n<2X} \varphi(n)=\frac{9}{\pi^2}X^2+O(X \log X)$$

Therefore, for any positive $s>2$ we have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\geq N} \frac{\varphi(n)}{n^s} &\geq \sum_{k\geq 0} 2^{-(k+1)s}N^{-s}\sum_{2^kN\leq n<2^{k+1}N} \varphi(n) \\
&\geq C\sum_{k\geq 0} 2^{-(k+1)s}N^{-s}2^{2k}N^2\\
&\geq C_0(s)N^{2-s}
\end{align*}
for some positive constants $C$ and $C_0(s)$.

Comment: Indeed, with a more careful version of this argument (partial summation) one can even get the asymptotic $$\sum_{n\geq N} \frac{\varphi(n)}{n^s} \sim \frac6{\pi^2} \frac{N^{2-s}}{s-2} \qquad(s>2).$$